# AttributeError: module 'keras_tuner.engine' has no attribute 'tuner'

Tags: python, keras-tuner

I am using google colab and i have been trying to import autokeras, however when i do so, I get this error below. I have tried !pip install autokeras. I have tried to updated tensorflow, autokeras, keras, and keras-tuner to fix it but this does not help. I am unsure how to solve this issue.

```
import autokeras as ak
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-85d187d68977> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import autokeras as ak

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/autokeras/__init__.py in <module>
     15 import keras_nlp
     16 
---> 17 from autokeras.auto_model import AutoModel
     18 from autokeras.blocks import BertBlock
     19 from autokeras.blocks import CategoricalToNumerical

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/autokeras/auto_model.py in <module>
     27 from autokeras import graph as graph_module
     28 from autokeras import pipeline
---> 29 from autokeras import tuners
     30 from autokeras.engine import head as head_module
     31 from autokeras.engine import node as node_module

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/autokeras/tuners/__init__.py in <module>
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 
---> 15 from autokeras.tuners.bayesian_optimization import BayesianOptimization
     16 from autokeras.tuners.greedy import Greedy
     17 from autokeras.tuners.hyperband import Hyperband

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/autokeras/tuners/bayesian_optimization.py in <module>
     15 import keras_tuner
     16 
---> 17 from autokeras.engine import tuner as tuner_module
     18 
     19 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/autokeras/engine/tuner.py in <module>
     28 
     29 
---> 30 class AutoTuner(keras_tuner.engine.tuner.Tuner):
     31     """A Tuner class based on KerasTuner for AutoKeras.
     32 

AttributeError: module 'keras_tuner.engine' has no attribute 'tuner'
```

I have tried to updated tensorflow, autokeras, keras, and keras-tuner to fix it but this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

As keras_tuner was updated (https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/master/keras_tuner/engine/tuner.py line 35), you must edit your file /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/autokeras/engine/tuner.py line 30 :

```
class AutoTuner(keras_tuner.Tuner):
```

Or simply :

```
pip install keras-tuner==1.3

pip install typing-extensions --upgrade
```

Comment: Please try to provide the PR of the change, the link you provided to the mainline code repository is likely to change over time, so this might not be accurate in the future. Also it is advisable to install packages inside of a virtual env.